# ASP.NET C# - Do you need seperate datasources for each gridview of different tables in same database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

Sorry, this is a bit of a noob question, but do you need a separate datasources for each gridview if each gridview is accessing the same database but different tables in the database?

For example: I have 3 different grid views dispaying searches for 1) given ZipCode and PlanCode, 2) given ZipCode, PlanCode, and Age, 3) given State Code and Carrier Code.

Here's the c# code-behind:

```
protected void Search_Zip_Plan_Age_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _with1 = this.ZipPlan_SqlDataSource;
    _with1.SelectParameters.Clear();

    string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PriceFinderConnectionString"]
    _with1.SelectCommand = "ssp_get_zipcode_plan";
    _with1.SelectParameters.Add("ZipCode", this.ZipCode.Text);
    _with1.SelectParameters.Add("PlanCode", this.PlanCode.Text);
    _with1.SelectParameters.Add("Age", this.Age.Text);        

    _with1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;

    _with1.CancelSelectOnNullParameter = false;


    Search_Results_GridView.DataBind();
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You could also avoid using DataSource controls altogether and do a manual binding. I typically write a data access layer and then I expose functions that return the various views of the data I need for binding to controls.

Comment: @FrankHale, thanks for the response. Do you use a stored procedure with that method and a dll file? Please send an example of the coding necessary on all the files as an answer if you have time. Do you have any idea on the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings error I am getting?

Comment: Try putting () after the call to .ToString. to see if that clears the error coming from the ConfigurationManager line.

Comment: As far as the data access layer goes I create a new class library for that which I reference from my web app. I keep it's functionality to only what is needed to interact and manipulate the database. You can use stored procedures if you like and then interface with them through whatever DB access method you use. I'm working with Linq to SQL here.

Comment: @FrankHale, can you send me a link on that? What's Linq? I found the problem. I rewrote it to: string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PriceFinderConnectionString"]

Comment: LINQ is Language Integrated Query. In short it allows you to query arbitrary data easily from within code. Here is a link for LINQ to SQL http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse data source controls only if its the same query; otherwise, you need different data source controls.

HTH.